# Image is not loading for html format in webview android

Tags: android, url, webview, android-webview, 360-degrees

Have created a functionality when user clicks on the image thumbnail, the main image will load by calling on the `WebView.loadurl(String.format())` method, the selected image will then be uploaded and displayed for the user to view. However, in this instances, when user clicks on the image thumbnail, the following message is displayed:

> The requested URL /projectname_uat/data/images/property/property_id/360/1/index.htm is not found on this server.

What has gone wrong in that instances?

Furthermore, when I copied the following url into a web browser: Google Chrome, it wasn't showing initially, however when I made the following changes, the images was showing in the web browser but not on the app device. What I do understand is that there is no difference between htm or html, and most the images that can be displayed are either in htm or html.

the following change that I have made, which is to change htm to html:

> /projectname_uat/data/images/property/property_id/360/1/index.**html**

Could anyone offer any assistance to this issue?? It has been bogging my mind for a couple of days and it is getting frustrating. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
int img_id = 1;
photoPb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.photoPb);
    photoPb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
 if (panoSize > 0) {
        g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery01);
        g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        int pad = 15;
        g.setSpacing(1);
        g.setUnselectedAlpha(255);
        g.setPadding(pad, 10, pad, pad);
        g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                img_id = position;
                setImageShade(position);
                captionText.setText(caption[position]);
                Log.i("PropertyPanoramaActvity:if(panoSize>0)","******webView.loadUrl******"+getString(R.string.app_360_domain)+getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+(img_id)+getString(R.string.app_360_index));
                //webView.loadUrl(String.format("https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property107/360/4/index.htm", id, img_id));
                webView.loadUrl(String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain)+getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+(img_id)+getString(R.string.app_360_index)));


            }
        });
    }
```

String.XML:

```
<string name="app_360_domain">https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/</string>
<string name="app_360_property">data/images/property/property</string>
<string name="app_360_directory">/360/</string>
<string name="app_360_index">/index.htm</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't change the `app_360_index` string value to be **/index.html**

Comment: still can't actually load the image, as in it either still gives a blank screen or the page is not found in ther server

Comment: Yeah, it is, it could display the images when I tested it out in the browser

Comment: logged? I have tried the url onto the web-browser and some of them works with htm and some works with html

Comment: Furthermore, there is no difference between htm and html right?

Comment: There is no practical differences between the two file, but if **.htm** is not present on the server you have to request for the **.html**

Comment: but all the files are saved as htm in the html 5 directory of the php

Comment: So do you have any other ideas why?

Comment: So you have to call the *.htm* instead of *.html* file. Can you update the code you're using right now?

Comment: the code is still the same, okay! i don't think you know what is the issue that I am facing.

Comment: All the image file that is saved in SQL database is in /index.htm format. The following string is now reference to /index.htm. However, some of the images cannot be found in the server when the entire url is typed into the browser and hence, images cannot be found and displayed in the android device.  Some images that can displayed in the browser but not the android device are referenced to /index.html instead of /index.htm. And some of the images that can displayed in the browser but not the android device are referenced as index.htm

Comment: that was the first issue. SECOND ISSUE: is that for images that can be displayed in the browser should be able to be displayed in the android device as well. HOWEVER, when the specific  url reference is called, the image (which I believe is uploaded) is not displayed, it gives a white screen with a refresh box image.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
webView.loadUrl( ""+getString(R.string.app_360_domain)+getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+(img_id++)+getString(R.string.app_360_index));
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that i remove `String.format` and add in ""? may i know what is the explanation to that?

Comment: May be String.format work not correct with your concatinated string? What is output Log.i?

Comment: the output log.i is :`https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property135/360/4/index.htm` that is when I click on that specific image thumbnail

Comment: it still doesn't work, it is still not showing, as in now it is a blank screen, furthermore, some images can loaded in html format, some in htm form when tested on the web browser

Comment: I see url in my browser https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property135/360/4/index.htm . I get error 404. I try open https://developer.dapoltd.com/spacetobe_uat/data/images/property/property135/360/4/index.html . It work fine. Change '.htm' to '.html' @Andrea Ascari was right

Comment: that was I did, but the error still persists, and some images that is displayed in the browser has got the directory of either htm or html, how do I rectify this?

Comment: But why log.i output string with index.htm, not index.html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68862/discussion-between-androidnoob-and-tapa-save).

Comment: the images that were displayed in the web browser, some of the directories listed were index.html and some of them were index.htm. I have included the index.htm as a String.
Now what I would like to know, is there any possible method or ways whereby directory can access both htm or html
and from what I understand about htm and html, is that there are no significance differences between them, hence, if the directory is stated as htm, the browser will automatically read it as html and retrieve the url data accordingly as in html format

Comment: are you still able o help?

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say why it is not showing image, but what I think now is the problem me be in back slashes. Try this:

1)

```
String urlToLoad = String.format(getString(R.string.app_360_domain) + getString(R.string.app_360_property)+(getIntent().getIntExtra("propertyId", 0))+getString(R.string.app_360_directory)+(img_id)+getString(R.string.app_360_index);
```

2) Then go to debug, and check urlToLoad value if it is opened in browser. 
3) If not '@' must be added at the start of url in order compiler understood that backslash is part of the url, not escape sign

Comment: I don't really follow your answer

Comment: Where would you add @ to?